# C++ Error: =! not compiling in text adventure game

Tags: c++, text

I just started learning C++ and am working on making a small game template thing for a text based adventure game and wanted some help with 2 things. One of those would be excluding answers, and the other making new questions pop up after one is answered and the output is given. I would consult the creator of the tutorial I was watching, but he never made it past part 2 and hasn't touched his youtube channel in 3 years. I tried taking the answers and replacing the input thing with `=!` instead of `==`. I've been using an online compiler (http://cpp.sh) for faster editing, so here is the crash log for that:

`23:25: error: no match for 'operator||' (operand types are 'bool' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}')
23:25: note: candidate is:
23:25: note: operator||(bool, bool) <built-in>
23:25: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'bool'
23:43: error: no match for 'operator||' (operand types are 'bool' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}')
23:43: note: candidate is:
23:43: note: operator||(bool, bool) <built-in>
23:43: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'bool'
23:60: error: no match for 'operator||' (operand types are 'bool' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}')
23:60: note: candidate is:
23:60: note: operator||(bool, bool) <built-in>
23:60: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'bool'`

And this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    string input;
    int hp = 100;
    int finalhp;
    cout << "Your HP: " << hp << endl;
    cout << "Walking in the DANK castle dungeon, you stumble upon a dying man. Would you like to finish him off?\n1. Yes\n2. No" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == "yes" || input == "Yes") {

        finalhp = hp - 5;
        cout << "You monster, you should have helped him. You are attacked by guilt. -5 HP. You are now at:" << finalhp << endl;
    }
    else if (input == "no" || input == "No"){

        finalhp = hp + 5;
        cout << "You spared the man's life. While he sits there peacefully recovering, he gives you a potion giving you 5 hp. You are now at: " << finalhp << endl;

    }

else if (input =! "yes" || input =! "Yes" || input =! "no" || input =! "No"){

        cout << "Quit babbling like an idiot and answer my question!";

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: I don't see a `#include <string>` anywhere.  Also [avoid using `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: It worked before, but I'll still add it. Between where do I add it? Also what can I do to get around using that?

Comment: Includes should be at the start if the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numerous typos.

```
input =! "yes" || input =! "Yes" || input =! "no" || input =! "No"
      ^^                ^^                ^^               ^^
```

should be

```
input != "yes" || input != "Yes" || input != "no" || input != "No"
```

If you look at [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the expression

```
input =! "yes" || input =! "Yes" || input =! "no" || input =! "No"
```

would be quite crazy, not the simple expression that you were thinking of.

Comment: THANK YOU. Oh my goodness. I can not believe I overlooked that. Still looking for help with how to reset questions too. Got any help for that?

Comment: @WumboTheElephant, what do you mean by *"how to reset questions"*?

Comment: How can I add more questions that play after the one shown in an efficient way, possibly with varying answers?

Comment: @WumboTheElephant, it's best if you make that a different question in SO.

Comment: Um, okay. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

`=!` is not an operator in C++.  The not-equal-to operator is `!=`.  Because of this, your last `else if` condition is not doing what you think it is.  It's basically doing

```
input = (!"yes" || input = (!"Yes" || input = (!"no" || input = !"No")))
```

which leads to your error about no `operator||(bool, std::string)` existing.